Difficulty in adapting the GRM when fitting a Bayesian Regression across environments using BGLR package in R
I am working on a study that consists of multiple plots (i.e. environments) on which different wheat varieties are grown. It is an unbalanced design, so not each variety grows on each plot. A genomic relationship matrix is calculated to quantify the relatedness between varieties. Different phenotypic traits (e.g. grain yield) are subsequently measured for each variety per environment.
I managed to fit a model for only the genotype effects for each environment (GBLUP) as follows:
library(BGLR)

# G-Matrix
G <- matrix(rexp(900, rate=.1), ncol=30)
rownames(G) <- 1:30
colnames(G) <-1:30

# Phenotype data
y <- rnorm(100)
env <- c(rep(1, 25), rep(2, 19), rep(3, 11), rep(4, 15), rep(5, 30))
a <- c(1:25, c(1, 3, 4:20), 1:11, c(1, 3 , 5, 7, 8:18), 1:30)
df_test <- data.frame(y, env, a)
colnames(df_test) <- c("Yield", "Env", "ID")
df_test$Env <- as.factor(df_test$Env)
df_test$ID <- as.factor(df_test$ID)


# Filter df for environment 1
df_test_1 <- df_test %>% filter(Env == 1)
df_test_1 <- droplevels(df_test_1)


# Adapt G-matrix accordingly
G_1 <- G[levels(df_test_1$ID), levels(df_test_1$ID)]

# Run model
model1 <- BGLR(y = df_test_1$Yield, ETA = list(G= list(K = G_1, model = 'RKHS')), 
               nIter = 12000, burnIn = 2000)


This works fine, but I am now having trouble fitting a model to the grain yield data across all environments, basically capturing the main effect of the environment and using the GRM as covariance structure.
As the each genotype or variety occurs only once in the GRM, but multiple times in the dataset (in different environments), I need to adapt the GRM by making it larger. I tried this by subsetting the GRM for each environment so that they only include the genotypes in that particular environment, and finally to join these GRMs per environment into one large GRM. This basically follows the example shown in box 2a of this paper (albeit in a more complicated way, as the example is based on a balanced design):
https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/g3journal/5/4/10.1534_g3.114.016097/5/016097_files4.pdf?Expires=1720371225&Signature=PH2OgAvVm6ZCqtBz9wLv37wV9HRMN6WPDaefwFRZ8BzIMZivd6fncid0JmNdL5xu~np-Ob4IDWhWHmwDK2ZP5~F2fdXqFaizAbeoA7mFSp2-ma7gyrLlFz3lrlZ1Zp3k7PqlPlc1aImwwpPKXBnJhsZhJIkI70O-yCWCqO1B8xb7d5LwGc7DQeNbSkGzMapJRiAjr2DvS8DBNs6NTnfGvx2wTl-nHFp-9IvTF2msYoojiQYujG0WK2fjn1ZfufZCQ3f0KIRaYCikH2nDLiMPpXG4RFb~SqYqCfwoPvz4u5HaBO0Pip5EsjCwTne5DKaZelJRcHDHui3cz2b68gy6Eg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIE5G5CRDK6RD3PGA
I first tried doing this by only filtering the rows of each G-matrix and leaving the same amount of columns per row. I then just added these matrices together row-wise. However, the matrix is then not square anymore which will lead to an error when fitting the model.
Filtering both rows and columns and subsequently adding columns and rows to the GRMs per environment with NAs to make sure the matrices have the same dimensions is also not a valid solution, as this also produces an error. So how could I adapt the GRM here in order to fit this model?
